# How can I know how many inputs there are in each cell of a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a dynamic javascript table, where a row is added everytime a button has been pressed, now I have a button which adds additional input fields to certain columns of the last row.

ANYWAY I need to know how many inputs have been added in EACH row, to do some calculations with respective inputs and put the result in the last column of each row.

So, I don't understand how to assign an "id" to each new iput so that it is understandable which row it is and which input (first,second?), so that I could refer to this inputs later...

[image]

What I have managed so far, is to assign to all inputs a class, and count how many inputs there are in the whole table and assign id's respectively (1, 2 ..).
But this doesn't satisfy me because I want the count to start anew if it's a different row.
Sorry, I am quite new to this.

```
function addROW ()

{
var T = document.getElementById ('tbl');
var ro = T.insertRow (-1);
for (var j = 0, J = T.rows [0].cells.length; j < J; j++)
   {
   var inp = document.createElement ('input');
   inp.id = inp.value = 'n' + (T.rows.length - 1) +'_' + j+'_'+'1';
   var ce = ro.insertCell (-1);
   ce.appendChild (inp);
   }
}


function addINPUT ()
{  
   var T = document.getElementById ('tbl');
   x = T.rows.length-1;

   var ro = T.insertRow (-1);
   for (var j = 0, J = T.rows [0].cells.length; j < J; j++)
   {
   var inp = document.createElement ('input');
   var ce = ro.insertCell (-1);
   ce.appendChild (inp);
   }

   T.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML = T.rows[x].cells[2].innerHTML + T.rows[x+1].cells[2].innerHTML;
   T.rows[x].cells[3].innerHTML = T.rows[x].cells[3].innerHTML + T.rows[x+1].cells[3].innerHTML;
   T.rows[x].cells[4].innerHTML = T.rows[x].cells[4].innerHTML + T.rows[x+1].cells[4].innerHTML;
   T.deleteRow(x+1);

}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you expect as output? An array with numbers, where each number represents the input-count in the row that corresponds to the array index?

Comment: NB: trying to create dynamic id attributes is rarely the right solution.

Comment: @trincot Yes, I think that would be perfect. and what could be a better solution?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(r=>console.log(r.querySelectorAll("input").length))`

Comment: @mplungjan      Thank you!